# Pandas read and parse Excel data that shows as a datetime, but shouldn't be a datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a system I am reading from that implemented a time tracking function in a pretty poor way - It shows the tracked working time as [hh]:mm in the cell.  Now this is problematic when attempting to read this data because when you click that cell the data bar shows 11:00:00 PM, but what that 23:00 actually represents is 23 hours of time spent and not 11PM.  So whenever the time is 24:00 or more you end up with 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM and on up ( 25:00 = 1/1/1900 01:00:00 AM).

So pandas picks up the 11:00:00 AM or 1/1/1900 01:00:00 AM when it comes into the dataframe.  I am at a loss as to how I would put this back into an INT for and get the number of hours in a whole number format 24, 25, 32, etc.

Can anyone help me figure out how to turn this horribly formatted data into the number of hours in int format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is where I ended and it does work:

```
for i in range(len(df['Planned working time'])) :
    pwt = df['Planned working time'][i]
    if len(str(df['Planned working time'][i]).split(' ')) > 1 :
        if str(str(pwt).split(' ')[0]).split('-')[0] == '1900' :
            workint = int(24)*int(str(str(pwt).split(' ')[0]).split('-')[2]) + int(str(pwt).split(' ')[1].split(':')[0])

    elif len(str(pwt).split(' ')) == 1 :
        if str(str(pwt).split(' ')[0]).split('-')[0] != '1900' :
            workint = int(str(pwt).split(' ')[0].split(':')[0])

    df.set_value(i, 'Planned working time', workint)
```

any suggested improvements are welcome, but this results in the correct int values in all cases.  Tested on over 14K rows of data.  This would likely have to be refined if there were minutes, but there are no cases where minutes show up in the data and the UI on the front end doesn't appear to actually allow minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `1/1/1900 01:00:00 AM` to represent 25 hours of elapsed time then this tells me your reference timestamp is `12/31/1899 00:00:00`.  Try the following:

```
time_delta = pd.Timestamp('1/1/1900 01:00:00 AM') - pd.Timestamp('12/31/1899 00:00:00')
# returns Timedelta('1 days 01:00:00')
```

You can get the total number of seconds by using the `Timedelta.total_seconds()` method:

```
time_delta.total_seconds()
# returns 90000.0
```

and then you could get the number of hours with

```
time_delta.total_seconds() / 3600.0
# returns 25.0
```

So try subtracting `pd.Timestamp('12/31/1899 00:00:00')` from your `DatetimeIndex` based on the year 1900 to get a `TimedeltaIndex`.  You can then leave your `TimedeltaIndex` as is or convert it to a `Float64Index` with `TimedeltaIndex.total_seconds()`.

Comment: This didn't work for me or maybe I tried to implement it wrong; I will post what I ended up doing.  Look forward to suggested improvements.

Comment: Sounds good.  What version of `python` and `pandas` are you using?

Comment: last night it was 3.6.5 and .23.4

Answer (score 1):

pandas is not at fault its the excel that is interpreting the data wrongly, 
Set the data to text in that column and it wont interpret as date.
then save the file and open through pandas and it should work fine.
other wise export as CSV and try to open in pandas.

Comment: This data is coming in as a direct read from a website.  I can't change the setting on the column.  It comes in as a Custom setting from their system.  The setting is [hh]:mm.  Downloading it to a local drive is what I am trying to avoid.  I also didn't say pandas was the problem.

Comment: Also, even using converters {'Planned working time' : str} still results in 1900-01-01 00:00:00 showing up.  I just don't know a way to duplicate what excel is doing when it shows 32:00 when the formatting is [hh]:mm even though the underlying data bar shows 1/1/1900 06:00:00 for that same displayed 32:00